# Python Convert Unicode-Hex utf-8 strings to Unicode strings

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

Have `s = u'Gaga\xe2\x80\x99s'` but need to convert to `t = u'Gaga\u2019s'`

How can this be best achieved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Where ever you decoded the original string, it was likely decoded with latin-1 or a close relative.  Since latin-1 is the first 256 codepoints of Unicode, this works:

```
>>> s = u'Gaga\xe2\x80\x99s'
>>> s.encode('latin-1').decode('utf8')
u'Gaga\u2019s'
```

Comment: Hi, what if I want to do the vice-versa, converting it from unicode representation to hexadecimal representation, as I'm sending the data to some system that expects the unicode data in hex format.

Comment: @securecurve, likely some form of encode. Ask a question with your specific requirements and sample input and output.

Answer (score 7):

```
s = u'Gaga\xe2\x80\x99s'
t = u'Gaga\u2019s'
x = s.encode('raw-unicode-escape').decode('utf-8')
assert x==t

print(x)
```

yields

```
Gaga’s
```

Comment: I get "GagaÔÇÖs" in my windows terminal

Comment: `print repr(t)` still yields `'Gaga\xe2\x80\x99s'`

Comment: @rocksportrocker, @Acorn `looks like he fixed that`.

Comment: thank-you!  @rocksportrocker, works too but can only accept one answer.

Comment: `raw-unicode-escape` is there to encode/decode `\u` escapes. That it happens to do a Latin-1 encode for characters below `\u0100` at the same time is a side-effect I'm not sure I'd want to rely on; I think Mark's version is the more commonly-used idiom for recovering mis-decoded-UTF-8.

Comment: @bobince: After some experimentation, I have to agree. Thanks for the warning. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @dbv: After studying this some more, I think Mark Tolonen has the better answer. In the interest of having SO report the best answer at the top, please consider accepting [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609776/python-convert-unicode-hex-utf-8-strings-to-unicode-strings/7610946#7610946) instead.

Comment: @unutbu: I applied Mark's and your method to our data and both worked.  But, have taken advice on-board and changed best answer.  Thank-you to everyone as these are typically tricky areas.

Answer (score 2):

```
import codecs

s = u"Gaga\xe2\x80\x99s"
s_as_str = codecs.charmap_encode(s)[0]
t = unicode(s_as_str, "utf-8")
print t
```

prints

```
u'Gaga\u2019s'
```

Comment: Curious about this.. I don't see a `codecs.charmap_encode` in the 2.7 or 3.3 Python docs, link?