# Unable to print Tamil character in Python

Tags: python, unicode, tamil

I am trying to use Tamil languge in Python. But ran into difficulties. Here is my code

```
U=u'\u0B83'
print U
```

This throws the error,

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0b83' in
>   position 0 : ordinal not in range(128)

My defaultencoding in ascii. As u0b83 is already in unicode, it should print the character in Tamil.

I tried to this too, # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-. But results are same.

How do I set this in unicode?

Comment: # --coding: utf-8 -- is for writing actual utf-8 charactters in your file. not /u0b83

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I needed is `raw-unicode-escape`.

If I use `encode('raw-unicode-escape').decode('utf-8')` everything works perfectly. I found the answer here, [Python Convert Unicode-Hex utf-8 strings to Unicode strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609776/python-convert-unicode-hex-utf-8-strings-to-unicode-strings)

Answer (score 5):

In Linux at least, you can set your locale to use UTF-8 before starting Python:

```
$ export LC_ALL=en_GB.utf8
$ python
```

You can of course use any locale with a compatible encoding (but I recommend UTF-8).

Alternatively, encode the string when outputting it:

```
>> print U.encode('utf-8')
ஃ
```